# Why tensorflow utilize less than 20% of GEFORCE 1080 ti (11GB)?

Tags: tensorflow, gpgpu

I'm training a NMT model using [tf-seq2seq](https://github.com/google/seq2seq) package by GEFORCE GTX 1080 ti (11GB). During training the model, executing `nvidia-smi` shows that the GPU volatile utilization is always less than 25% while all CPU cores are busy. Why?

[image: nvidia-smi]

How can I find if I leverage all the potential of my GPU?

Answer (score 1):

The model in the above experiment was too small to leverage all the potential of the GPU.

Enlarging the model (leverage more layers, increase the size of vocabulary in use, increase the length of sequences,...) leads to better utilization (less than 80-90%) in the above experiments.